# Code working at jsFiddle but not at localhost on development server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some way to find how could be possible that the same code works on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ot96p9mL/2/) but doesn't at localhost development environment. This is drive me crazy since I don't know where to find or what to test in order to get the mistake at localhost side.

What is working in both sides?

- The "toggle all" functionality by check the first checkbox at top
- Mark each checkbox independent

What is working in jsFiddle but not in localhost?

- If you first toggle all using the first checkbox and then uncheck any checkbox you'll see how the first is unchecked too, this is the right and it works only on jsFiddle but not in localhost

So, in order to get where the problem is what test will you do on localhost? I mean don't know some `console.log()` or alert or something else to get a clue because I don't know what else to do. And code are exactly the same. Also I don't get any error on the console. Any advice?

**EDIT: Include code**

This is the code that I'm talking about as requested from some users:

```
$(function () {
    function marcarTodosCheck(selChk, tableBody) {
        $(selChk).on('click', function () {
            var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
            $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle);
        });

        $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
            if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(selChk).prop("checked", false);
            } else if ($(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").length == $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
                $(selChk).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
    }

    marcarTodosCheck('#toggleCheckboxNorma', '#resultadoNormaBody');

});
```

**Testing**

Ok, trying to find the cause because the code fails on localhost I did this:

```
function marcarTodosCheck(selChk, tableBody) {
    $(selChk).on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle);
    });

    $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            console.log('no estoy marcado' + !$(this).is(':checked'));
            $(selChk).prop("checked", false);
        } else if ($(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").length == $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
            console.log('si estoy marcado' + $(this).is(':checked'));
            $(selChk).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
}

marcarTodosCheck('#toggleCheckboxNorma', '#resultadoNormaBody');
```

But surprise none `console.log()` is executed, which makes me think, why?

**Clarify some points**

Ok, maybe I forgot in first to tell this, in the jsFiddle example data is loaded by default I mean it exists on the modal, now in my code, data is loaded through this jQuery code which made a Ajax call and add `tr` dynamically and perhaps there is the problem on why the code doesn't work at localhost:

```
$('button#btnBuscar').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post(Routing.generate('filtrarNormas'), $('#buscadorNorma').serialize(), 'json')
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.entities.length > 0) {
                    $('#resultadoNorma').show();

                    var $html = '';
                    data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                        $html += '<tr>';
                        $html += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' + value.id + '"></td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.codigo + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.norma + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.anno + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.comiteTecnico + '</td>';
                        $html += '</tr>';
                    });

                    $("table tbody#resultadoNormaBody").html($html);
                }
            })
            .fail();
});
```

Also as you notice the `#resultadoNorma` is hide by default and I show it only if I got results from Ajax call. Here is the original HTML:

```
<table  class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="resultadoNorma" style="display: none">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="toggleCheckboxNorma" name="toggleCheckboxNorma" /></th>
            <th>Nro.</th>
            <th>Norma COVENIN</th>
            <th>Año de Publicación</th>
            <th>Comité Técnico</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="resultadoNormaBody">

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your script included?

Comment: Show your code... otherwise we can't help.

Comment: @tymeJV yes it's include, but nevermind for someone here is more easy downvote the question to give some help!

Comment: @DanielCooley the code is on the Fiddle

Comment: @ReynierPM -- Is it being loaded? If you check the network tab is there a 200 code by the script?

Comment: @tymeJV yes it's loaded also, as I said all is working except for this "If you first toggle all using the first checkbox and then uncheck any checkbox you'll see how the first is unchecked too, this is the right and it works only on jsFiddle but not in localhost"

Comment: Can't help much...triple check that the HTML structure is what you want and throw some logs inside the function.

Comment: don't forget that fiddle default settings automatically wrap code in an `onload` handler

Comment: @charlietfl I have it on `domReady` and I tried on Fiddle but changing from `onLoad` to `onDomready` and works too, very weird

Comment: Is it an external file that may have been cached by the browser?  Try pressing `Ctrl + F5` to clear the browser cache on refresh against your development server version.

Comment: make sure that you included to your page not only `jQuery` but also `bootstrap` files, as in jsFiddle example

Comment: @entropic I'm trying in a Firefox Private Window so cache might not be the problem

Comment: try to use browser console by inspect element then there should be console or network tab in fire fox, there you can see what is going wrong and what is the cause

Comment: @Anarion both are included is the same scenario I'm getting crazy, must be some tiny mistake but so tiny that I'm not able to find it

Comment: The private window only clears the cache after you've fully closed it.  Are you closing it, then opening it again every time?

Comment: @entropic no, I don't but `CTRL+R` or `CTRL+F5` will do the job, right?

Comment: Yes, that should clear the cache on refresh.

Comment: Please include your code here, so that it is preserved for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Sorry... didn't see the link to the code before...

Comment: Try uploading your html+js somewhere in the web and give us a link to investigate your issue

Comment: @Anarion thanks but it's complicated to do this, is not a simple page is a huge Symfony2 application and this is just a small part

Comment: See my answer... do you HAVE to use onLoad or or domReady?

Comment: @ReynierPM You may simply create an html file, include all js and try if it works. Probably these js works fine but the issue is somewhere in your backend

Comment: @Anarion well I don't know what else to think/say, take a look at my latest edition

Comment: @ReynierPM try console.log your `$(tableBody).find("input:checkbox")` length first. Probably script doesn't see any

Comment: @Anarion perhaps due to the latest info I added to the main post, could you take a look?

Comment: Definitely. In dynamic content you should use this `$(tableBody).on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () { ... });`

Comment: @Anarion if it's not much to ask can you add your answer with your solution for future visitors? Will be nice to have another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, it works for me on localhost.  Instead of onLoad or whatnot, I used the standard `$(document).ready` function.

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    marcarTodosCheck('#toggleCheckboxNorma', '#resultadoNormaBody');
});
function marcarTodosCheck(selChk, tableBody) {
    $(selChk).on('click', function () {
        var $toggle = $(this).is(':checked');
        $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", $toggle);
    });

    $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").on('click', function () {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", false);
        } else if ($(tableBody).find("input:checkbox").length == $(tableBody).find("input:checkbox:checked").length) {
            $(selChk).prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you are dynamically adding content to the table, you might have to call the function again after every AJAX request... try adding the function call there as well...

```
$('button#btnBuscar').on('click', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post(Routing.generate('filtrarNormas'), $('#buscadorNorma').serialize(), 'json')
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                if (data.entities.length > 0) {
                    $('#resultadoNorma').show();

                    var $html = '';
                    data.entities.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                        $html += '<tr>';
                        $html += '<td><input type="checkbox" value="' + value.id + '"></td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.codigo + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.norma + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.anno + '</td>';
                        $html += '<td>' + value.comiteTecnico + '</td>';
                        $html += '</tr>';
                    });

                    $("table tbody#resultadoNormaBody").html($html);
                    marcarTodosCheck('#toggleCheckboxNorma', '#resultadoNormaBody');
            })
            .fail();
});
```